# Fill dynamically-sized Rectangle with a RadialGradient sized to fit perfectly using SwiftUI in Swift 5.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gradient, radial-gradients

I've got a **SwiftUI** screen that displays data in a grid format, dynamically sizing the cells so that they always fill the width available, and making sure they are always squares.

I've got the layout working nicely, but the gradients are a little frustrating.  When creating a **RadialGradient**, you need to specify **beginRadius** and **endRadius** in actual screen points, rather than unit points (from 0.0 to 1.0).

Like this:

```swift
RadialGradient(gradient: item.isBlue ? self.blue : self.red,
               center: .center,
               startRadius: 0.0,
               endRadius: 100.0)
```

In the example above, I've picked an arbitrary size of **100 points** for the **endRadius**.  This works just fine, but really gives the squares a different look when they are different sizes.  Check out the two examples below.

**Example 1 -- 3x2 grid**:

[image: 3x2 grid]

**Example 2 -- 2x3 grid:**

[image: 2x3 grid]

Here's all the code in an example project **ContentView.swift** which demonstrates clearly what I mean:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyDataItem: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let text: String
    let isBlue: Bool
}

struct MyDataRow: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let items: [MyDataItem]
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var datasetIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var sets = [
        // First data set
        [
            MyDataRow(items: [
                MyDataItem(text: "A", isBlue: false),
                MyDataItem(text: "B", isBlue: true),
                MyDataItem(text: "C", isBlue: true),
            ]),
            MyDataRow(items: [
                MyDataItem(text: "D", isBlue: false),
                MyDataItem(text: "E", isBlue: false),
                MyDataItem(text: "F", isBlue: false),
            ]),
        ],

        // Second data set
        [
            MyDataRow(items: [
                MyDataItem(text: "A", isBlue: false),
                MyDataItem(text: "B", isBlue: true),
            ]),
            MyDataRow(items: [
                MyDataItem(text: "C", isBlue: true),
                MyDataItem(text: "D", isBlue: false),
            ]),
            MyDataRow(items: [
                MyDataItem(text: "E", isBlue: false),
                MyDataItem(text: "F", isBlue: false),
            ]),
        ]
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $datasetIndex, label: Text("Pick a data set")) {
                Text("Set 1").tag(0)
                Text("Set 2").tag(1)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            GridThing(rows: self.$sets[self.datasetIndex])
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct GridThing: View {
    @Binding var rows: [MyDataRow]

    private let spacing: CGFloat = 20.0

    let blue = Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color(red: 0.85, green: 0.85, blue: 1.0)])
    let red = Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.85, blue: 0.85)])

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
            ForEach(self.rows) { row in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: self.spacing) {
                    ForEach(row.items) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: item.isBlue ? self.blue : self.red,
                                                     center: .center,
                                                     startRadius: 0.0,
                                                     endRadius: 100.0))
                                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                            Text(item.text)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have the **RadialGradient** use an endRadius that matches the height and width of the square.

I'd love it to be able to do this automatically.  **LinearGradient**, for example, takes **UnitPoint** for **startPoint** and **endPoint**, which would be perfect, but for **RadialGradient** we need to do all the work I guess.

My main thought on this is to somehow incorporate a **GeometryReader**.

I've tried to wrap it like this, calculating an **endRadius** with the **GeometryReader**.  This one fails because *"the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"*:

```swift
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
            GeometryReader { geom in
            ForEach(self.rows) { row in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: self.spacing) {
                    ForEach(row.items) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: item.isBlue ? self.blue : self.red,
                                                     center: .center,
                                                     startRadius: 0.0,
                                                     endRadius: (geom.size.width - (self.spacing * (row.items.count + 1))) / row.items.count))
                                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                            Text(item.text)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that it is a bug that RadialGradient doesn't use UnitPoint coordinates for startRadius and endRadius, so I've filed FB7562363 about it.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry reader is correct, but instead of wrapping the whole grid, just wrapped square and then you don't need to do any extra computations: the geometry width is the width of the square and that's twice the radius of your gradient.  here's a playground:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct V: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
      ForEach(0..<4) { row in
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
          ForEach(0..<4) { item in
            ZStack {
              GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                  .fill(
                    RadialGradient(
                      gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.red, Color.green]),
                      center: .center,
                      startRadius: 0.0,
                      endRadius: geometry.size.width / 2 )
                   )
                  .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
              }
              Text("text")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(V())
```

Comment: Hi Josh -- this looks good in your example, but it breaks if you do more rows than fit on the screen.  For example, make your first ForEach to be "ForEach(0..<15)".  The size of the rectangles breaks in that case (they become tiny, apparently in an attempt to fit them all vertically).  I tried wrapping the whole thing in a scrollview but that didn't help.  And I tried putting .frame(maxSize: .infinity) attached to the VStack as well.